# Testing against one of several values in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Apologies I have no coding experience.

This line of code is resisting my report from exporting all product_types. Is it possible to change this to `product_type="ALL"` or `product_type='configurable','other'`?

```
    <xsl:if test="(product_type='configurable')">
```

I've obviously tried to make the changes above but they don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO: XSL if: test with multiple test conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21381055/7478597)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Always:**

```
<xsl:if test="true()">
```

**Never:**

```
<xsl:if test="false()">
```

**Multiple cases (XSLT 1.0):**

```
<xsl:if test="(product_type = 'configurable') or (product_type = 'other')">
```

**Multiple cases (XSLT 2.0+):**

```
<xsl:if test="product_type = ('configurable', 'other')">
```

**Defined, regardless of value:**

```
<xsl:if test="product_type">
```