# Can you use "If" with two conditions (XSLT) Oracle Bi Publisher RTF Template

Tags: oracle, xslt, rtf, bi-publisher

Inside a for-each, we have a choose the multiple when conditions.

What I need to do is this- In simple terms

WHEN a certain variable equals a value, If value 1 = somevalue and value 2 = someothervalue -> Do Something

Here is what I have.  I have tried various forms and iterations and nothing seems to work either erroring when previewing or seemingly ignoring the code.  I have done If then else, If and, as well as When and -  I inherited this object and was not the original developer -  ** at the two statements I am having trouble with.  Any help is much appreciated.  I can attach some source XML if needed.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'ACKIMPORT', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'ACKMATSURG', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'ACKTERMS', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'CARBCOMP', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'CPSC', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'DISCLAIMER', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'EXPORTREG', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'FLAME', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'INTRATE', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'REMITTO', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'SVCCHARGE', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'INV_1', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'INV_2', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'ACKTERMS_I', '')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'INVTERMS_I', '')?>
<?for-each:Print_Messages_S22?>
<?choose:?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKTERMS_I'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKTERMS_I', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INVTERMS_I'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INVTERMS_I', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INV_1_EN'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INV_1', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INV_1_ENFR'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INV_1', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INV_2_EN'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INV_2', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INV_2_ENFR'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INV_2', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKIMPORT'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKIMPORT', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKIMPOR_F'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKIMPORT', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKMATSURG'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKMATSURG', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKMATSU_F'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKMATSURG', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKTERMS'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKTERMS', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='ACKTERMS_F'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'ACKTERMS', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='CARBCOMP'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'CARBCOMP', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='CPSC'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'CPSC', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='DISCLAIMER'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'DISCLAIMER', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='DISCLAIM_F'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'DISCLAIMER', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='EXPORTREG'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'EXPORTREG', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='FLAME'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'FLAME', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INTRATE'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INTRATE', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='INTRATE_F'?>
<?if:../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'INTRATE', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='SVCCHARGE'?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'SVCCHARGE', PrintMessage_ID3)?>
<?end when?>
**<?when:MessageID_ID5='REMITTO_CA'?>
<?xdofx:if ../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'
then <?if:../CurrencyCodeFrom_ID18='USD'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'REMITTO', PrintMessage_ID3)?>)<?end if?>
else  
end if?>
<?end when?>**
<?when:MessageID_ID5='REMITTO_IN'?>
<?if:../OrderType_ID46='S5' and UserReservedReference_ID6?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'REMITTO', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?if:../OrderType_ID46='X5' and UserReservedReference_ID6?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'REMITTO', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
<?when:MessageID_ID5='REMITTO_US'?>
<?if:not(../OrderType_ID46='S7')?><?if:not(../OrderType_ID46='C7')?><?if:not(../OrderType_ID46='X7')?><?if:not(../UserReservedReference_ID6)?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'REMITTO', PrintMessage_ID3)?><?end if?><?end if?><?end if?><?end if?>
<?end when?>
**<?when:MessageID_ID5='REMITTO_CD'?>
<?xdofx:if ../Sold_To_Country_ID47='CA'
then <?if:../CurrencyCodeFrom_ID18='CAD'?><?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'REMITTO', PrintMessage_ID3)?>)<?end if?>
else  
end if?>
<?end when?>**
<?end chose?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381055/xsl-if-test-with-multiple-test-conditions

Comment: Can you produce a smaller or simpler example that demonstrates the problem?